# How do I make it so that when I press a key an image pops up and stays there until i let go?

Tags: python, pygame

I am basically trying to do what the question says but its not happening. Can anyone explain why?

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        screen.blit(player_1, [170, 333])
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        screen.blit(player_1, [331, 500])
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        screen.blit(player_1, [170, 665])
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        screen.blit(player_1, [10, 500])
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        screen.blit(player_2, [195, 333])
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        screen.blit(player_2, [356, 500])
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        screen.blit(player_2, [196, 665])
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        screen.blit(player_2, [35, 500])
```

Comment: Your indenting is off for Python: code within an `if` statement must be indented, and the top level `if` isn't in your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of holding your key down. Try using a Boolean statement bonded to the key you want to pop up an image. Would look something similar to this

```
 Keys[pygame.K_UP] = false
    If Keys[pygame.K_UP] == true:
         Print "(insert image url here)"
         Else
                (Do nothing)
```

Comment: Also seems your first if statement is dependent on the down key being pressed. Therefore you will not enter your other if loops without first having this initial key to iterate past your key variable decleration